# Файл не запускается из cmd (python)

Tags: python, cmd

Питон установлен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл имеется
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результата ноль
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `python3 a.py` ?

Comment: нужно добавить python в PATH (либо в ручную в системных переменных, либо при установке/переустановке выбрать кажется *custom*, или как оно там правильно называется, и там поставить галку на "добавить в PATH")

Comment: @Bogdan, т.е. мне переустановить питон?

Comment: @AntonKucenko, да, я его только что создал

Comment: @samsusam, можете переустановить, можете вручную залезть в системные переменные и добавить папку с питоном в PATH. Я б посоветовал все таки почитать про PATH и попробовать сделать это вручную, т.к. довольно часто встречаются подобного рода проблемы.

Comment: @samsusam введите не `python a.py`, а `python3 a.py`

Comment: @Bogdan, спасибо, вопрос решил, с path разобрался, щас поправлю вопрос. Может кому поможет

Comment: @AntonKucenko, спасибо за участие))) разобрался.

Answer (score 4):

Решение:

1. нашел исполняемый файл с питоном (клик правой на иконке, "открыть расположение")
2. скопировал путь к нему (у меня: 
   C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36)
3. Далее: открыл Проводник, нашел "этот компьютер", в контекстном меню выбрал "свойства", в открывшемся окне слева "дополнительные параметры системы", далее справа внизу "переменные среды", далее, в окне "Системные переменные" нашел переменную "path", выделил ее (просто один раз щелкнуть лев.кн.мыши), внизу нажал "изменить", в открывшемся окне нажал "создать" и в открывшееся поле вставил адрес из п.2, затем "ОК", и перезагрузил комп.
4. после перезагрузки, в командной строке ввел команду `python -V`, убедился, что питон есть и именно нужной мне версии... ну а затем все получилось.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]